# Postgresql - 9.1 IN Parameter changed the sorted order

Tags: postgresql, orm

I have some ids its already be in sorted order (65826 ,78555,456666) . I passed this input in select query to get data, but in the output the sort order will changed and returns result as (456666,65826,78555);

`select sku_id from blc_sku where sku_id in(65826 ,78555,456666)` but the output return as

> ```
> sku_id
>
> 65286
> 78555
> 456666
> ```

but expected result,

> ```
> sku_id
>
> 456666
> 65286
> 78555
> ```

Please help me to resolve this ...

Comment: Thanks Vao Tsun. It works fine..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
t=> with v(a) as (values (2),(1),(3))
select * from v
t-> where a in (1,2,3)
t-> ;
 a
---
 2
 1
 3
(3 rows)
```

you see the result is in order the data is met, not in order you set in `IN`. Postgres does not guarantee such behaviour though (and you can't predict the order how data is met - it depends on cache and other things I have no knowledge about). If you want ordered result set use `ORDER` directive:

```
t=> with v(a) as (values (2),(1),(3))
select * from v
where a in (1,2,3)
order by a desc;
 a
---
 3
 2
 1
(3 rows)
```

In case you have an preordered list, you can join initial data against it, like here:

```
t=> with v(a) as (values (2),(1),(3))
, ordered (v,o) as (values(1,0), (2,1), (3,2))
select v.* from v
join ordered on v.a=ordered.v
order by o;
 a
---
 1
 2
 3
(3 rows)
```